# React Buttons change color from parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and making a simple quiz where the div changes color based on if the solution is correct or not, but I want to reset the color when the "Next" or "Previous" question is selected from the parent component. I tried creating a prop called `clearColor` and when that is true reset the color from within the  component but this isn't quite working. I was wondering how to best go about this? Because I am so new to react I wasn't even quite sure what to google so any help is appreciated!

```js
class Button extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.initialState = this.state
  }

  getInitialState = () => ({
      bgColor: ""
  })

  resetState = () => {
    if (this.props.clearColor) {
      this.setState(this.initialState)
    }
  }

  boxClick = (e) => {
    if (this.props.isCorrect) {
      this.setState({
        bgColor: "#9ef0bc"
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        bgColor: "#f56342"
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div className="boxClickCss" 
          style={{backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor}} 
          onClick={this.boxClick}>{this.props.name}</div>
    );
  }
}

function Quiz() {
    const questions = [
        {
            questionText: 'What is the capital of France?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'New York', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'London', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Paris', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'Dublin', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'Who is CEO of Tesla?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'Jeff Bezos', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Elon Musk', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'Bill Gates', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Tony Stark', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'The iPhone was created by which company?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'Apple', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'Intel', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Amazon', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Microsoft', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'How many Harry Potter books are there?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: '1', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: '4', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: '6', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: '7', isCorrect: true },
            ],
        },
    ];

    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = React.useState(0);
    const [clearColor, setClearColor] = React.useState(false)

    const nextClicked = () => {
        setClearColor(true);
        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < questions.length) {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        }
    };

    const previousClicked = () => {
        setClearColor(true)
        if (currentQuestion <= 0) {
            setCurrentQuestion(0);
        } else {
            const nextQuestion = currentQuestion - 1;
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='quiz'>
        <div className='app'>
                    <div className='question-section'>
                        <div className='question-count'>
                            <span>Question {currentQuestion + 1}</span>/{questions.length}
                        </div>
                        <div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='answer-section'>
                        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                            <Button name={answerOption.answerText} isCorrect={answerOption.isCorrect} clearColor={clearColor} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div className='buttons'>
              <button className="prev" onClick={() => previousClicked()}>Previous</button>
                <button className="next" onClick={() => nextClicked()}>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Quiz />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
* {
  font-family: "Verdana", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: #014650;
}

body {
  background-color: #014650;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.score-section {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 24px;
  align-items: center;
}

/* QUESTION/TIMER/LEFT SECTION */
.question-section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.question-count {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.question-count span {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.question-text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.timer-text {
  background: rgb(230, 153, 12);
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 189, 67);
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* ANSWERS/RIGHT SECTION */
.answer-section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.boxClickCss {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #014650;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid #234668;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.boxClickCss:hover {
  background-color: #6A939A;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7BC8C3;
  background-color: #252d4a;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid #234668;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.correct {
  background-color: #2f922f;
}

.incorrect {
  background-color: #ff3333;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #555e7d;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button svg {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.prev {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.next {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.quiz {
  background-color: #DEF2F0;
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: min-content;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 42px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-
dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
</div>
```

I also have a codepen here if that is easier to work with: https://codepen.io/mayagans/pen/mdOypGG?editors=1111 I tried looking into lifting up state so I can change the `bgColor` in the parent  component but I'm not sure that is react-y? Any help on how to tackle this appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. I would just lift all the state up to Quiz component. Also would keep boxClick function in Quiz component and pass it to Button component. And I am colouring the button only which title match currently selected answer using setAnswer hook.

```
const Button = ({answer, name, bgColor, isCorrect, boxClick, setAnswer}) => {

  return (
    <div className="boxClickCss" 
          style={{backgroundColor: (answer === name) && bgColor}} 
          onClick={(e) => {
            boxClick(isCorrect)
            setAnswer(name)
          }}>
        {name}
    </div>
  )
}

const Quiz = () => {

  const questions = [
        {
            questionText: 'What is the capital of France?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'New York', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'London', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Paris', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'Dublin', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'Who is CEO of Tesla?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'Jeff Bezos', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Elon Musk', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'Bill Gates', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Tony Stark', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'The iPhone was created by which company?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'Apple', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'Intel', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Amazon', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'Microsoft', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'How many Harry Potter books are there?',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: '1', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: '4', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: '6', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: '7', isCorrect: true },
            ],
        },
];

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = React.useState(0);
  const [bgColor, setbgColor] = React.useState('')
  const [answer, setAnswer] = React.useState('')


  const boxClick = isCorrect => {
     if(isCorrect) {
       setbgColor("#9ef0bc")
     } else {
       setbgColor("#f56342")
     }
   }

    const nextClicked = () => {
        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < questions.length) {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        }
    };

    const previousClicked = () => {
        if (currentQuestion <= 0) {
            setCurrentQuestion(0);
        } else {
            const nextQuestion = currentQuestion - 1;
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);

        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='quiz'>
        <div className='app'>
                    <div className='question-section'>
                        <div className='question-count'>
                            <span>Question {currentQuestion + 1}</span>/{questions.length}
                        </div>
                        <div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='answer-section'>
                        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                            <Button name={answerOption.answerText} isCorrect={answerOption.isCorrect} boxClick={boxClick} bgColor={bgColor} setAnswer={setAnswer} answer={answer} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div className='buttons'>
              <button className="prev" onClick={() => previousClicked()}>Previous</button>
                <button className="next" onClick={() => nextClicked()}>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Quiz />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I really like how you moved the color up by tracking the correct answer for each button, this is really awesome code thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to lsiten to props changes during componentDidUdpate like this, to check:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.clearColor && this.state.bgColor) {
      this.setState(this.initialState)
    }
  }
```

Moving the state up is reacty and you could be using that.
I would recommend that or moving it into a context.
Also maybe look into function components, which will be the main way to write react in the future.

Comment: This is awesome, just spent a lot of time reading up on componentDidUpdate so thank you! I was curious though, this works the first time I click "Next" but now for the second question the buttons don't change color, is this because I need to also reset (updated pen here) https://codepen.io/mayagans/pen/mdOypGG I think this may have to do with the this.props.clearColor? Thank you again!